# How to insert multiple strings into a sqlite table using dbadapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to insert the values inside 2 strings into a table using dbadapter.
I am able to insert one string named as 'inputparticulars' to  a column named
as 'TX_PARTICULARS'. How to insert another the value from another string
'inputamount' to another column named as 'TX_AMOUNT' in the same row.

```
public void onTxClick(View v) {
    String inputparticulars = particulars.getText().toString();
    String inputamount = amount.getText().toString();
    ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
    vivzHelper.insertTxData(inputparticulars);
}

public long insertTxData(String inputparticulars) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_PARTICULARS, inputparticulars);
    //contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_AMOUNT, inputamount);
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_DATE, Calendar.DATE);
    long id = db.insert(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, null, contentvalues);
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass those two value to the `insertTxData`method. So you may change your method like this.

```
public void insertTxData(String inputparticulars, String inputamount) {

  SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
  contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_PARTICULARS,inputparticulars);
  contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_AMOUNT, inputamount);
  contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_DATE, Calendar.DATE);
  db.insert(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, null, contentvalues );
  db.insert(VivzHelper.TX_AMOUNT, null, inputamount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or as @Alex Chengalan say, but you should better pass an object as parameter, and then get the properties in your insert method, like this:

this will be your Plain Old Java Object (POJO)

```
public class YourObject{
String YourId,YourString;

public YourObject(String YourId, String YourString) {
    super();
    this.YourId= YourId;
    this.YourString= YourString;
}

public String getYourId() {
    return YourId;
}

public void setYourId(String YourId) {
    this.YourId= YourId;
}

public String getYourString() {
    return YourString;
}

public void setYourString(String YourString) {
    this.YourString= YourString;
}
}
```

And in your method to insert into DB:

```
public void insertEntry(YourObject obj)
{
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put("dbField1", obj.getYourID());
    newValues.put("dbField2", obj.getYourString());
    db.insert(table, null, newValues);
}
```

So as you can see, you just have to create properties in your Pojo (Object Class), and then just call the method that you want to assign in your column's table.

P.D.
I Recommend to learn about some ORM for android, GreenDao is good, and it is easy.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass an array of your objects to the method. For example:

```
public long insertTxData(String[] inputs) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_PARTICULARS, inputs[0]);
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_AMOUNT, inputs[1]);

    //....other parameters

    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_DATE, Calendar.DATE);
    long id = db.insert(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, null, contentvalues);
    return id;
}
```